# Programmatically simulate GPS location in iOS tests

Tags: ios, swift, gps, automated-tests, xctest

I would like to write UI tests in Swift that make screenshots of various places of a map in our app. In order to do this, I need to simulate fake GPS data during the test.

There are some solutions like this one (https://blackpixel.com/writing/2016/05/simulating-locations-with-xcode-revisited.html) that use GPX files and simulate the location with `Debug > Simulate Location` in Xcode, but I need this to be completely automated. Ideal would be something similar to the `LocationManager` in Android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had similar problems when writing UI tests, because the simulator / tethered device can't do everything you might want. What I do is write mocks that mimic the desired behavior (of something I would normally have no control over).

Substituting a custom location manager for the CLLocationManager will allow you to take full control of location updates, as you can programmatically send the location updates through the CLLocationManagerDelegate method: `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`.

Create a class `MyLocationManager`, make it a subclass of `CLLocationManager`, and have it override all the methods you call. Don't call super in the overridden methods, as CLLocationManager should never actually receive a method call.

```
class MyLocationManager: CLLocationManager {
  override func requestWhenInUseAuthorization() {
    // Do nothing.
  }

  override func startUpdatingLocation() {
    // Begin location updates. You can use a timer to regularly send the didUpdateLocations method to the delegate, cycling through an array of type CLLocation.
  }

  // Override all other methods used.

}
```

The `delegate` property doesn't need to be overridden (and can't be), but you have access to it as a subclass of CLLocationManager.

To use `MyLocationManager` you should pass in launch arguments that tell your app if it is a UITest or not. In your test case's `setUp` method insert this line of code:

```
app.launchArguments.append("is_ui_testing")
```

Store CLLocationManager as a property that is a MyLocationManager when testing. When not testing CLLocationManager will be used as normal.

```
static var locationManger: CLLocationManager = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.contains("is_ui_testing") ? MyLocationManager() : CLLocationManager()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for purposes of (unit) testing, you can swizzle the `startUpdatingLocation` method to instruct the `CLLocationManager` instance to behave as you want.

Here's a possible implementation:

```swift
// Just a wrapper to allow storing weak references in an array
struct WeakRef<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var value: T?
}

extension CLLocationManager {
    
    // Replace the `startUpdatingLocation` method with our own
    private static var swizzled = false
    static func swizzle() {
        guard !swizzled else { return }
        swizzled = true
        method_exchangeImplementations(class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(startUpdatingLocation))!,
                                       class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(swizzledStartUpdatingLocation))!)
    }
    
    // When a CLLocationManager is asked to `startUpdatingLocation`,
    // it adds itself to the list of registered instances
    // Using weak references to allow managers to deallocate when needed
    static var registeredInstances = [WeakRef<CLLocationManager>]()
    @objc func swizzledStartUpdatingLocation() {
        Self.registeredInstances.append(WeakRef(value: self))
        if let mockedLocation = Self.mockedLocation {
            delegate?.locationManager?(self, didUpdateLocations: [mockedLocation])
        }
    }
    
    // This is the mocked location, when it changes
    // all registered managers notify their delegates with the new mocked location
    static var mockedLocation: CLLocation? {
        didSet {
            guard let mockedLocation = mockedLocation else { return }
            registeredInstances.forEach {
                guard let manager = $0.value else { return }
                manager.delegate?.locationManager?(manager, didUpdateLocations: [mockedLocation])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this is just a basic implementation `stopUpdatingLocation` should also be swizzled to remove the manager. Other features of `CLLocationMangager` can also be implemented/swizzled in the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. CLLocationManager is giving you your location with the help of a delegate, you have any way to set this location.

You can make a CLLocationManager simulator class that give some locations over the time.
Or you can sync your test with a timestamped GPX.

Comment: Is this seriously not possible at all? 
So my best bet would be to use a timestamped GPX file and take a screenshot each time the position changes?

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to bind XCTest to a local web server which would simulate the location, for instance, via [idb](https://github.com/facebook/idb). For more details feel free to check out this [blog post](https://testableapple.com/note-35). Hope it helps.